# Webkit scrollbar thumb not working on Safari 14

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I'm facing some problems to add scrollbar color on safari 14. The webkit works in chrome and edge, but not in safari. There are some threads saying that safari isn't supporting webkit, but if that's true, is there a way to add the color to the scrollbar?

example from w3schools.com,

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: could you provide a working code example?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h0j935r6/1/ its working in my safari browser

Comment: sorry, I can't provide and example. But is your os updated? Or did you try a different color?

Comment: Its working in my safari browser too

Comment: Also with different colors: https://jsfiddle.net/hc9z4pwo/